How to implement custom function in calcite that take interval as an argument?
I need to add a custom function (like sequence() in spark) to Calcite that takes an interval as a parameter.
public class SequenceFunction {
    public List eval(Date start, Date end, IntervalSqlType interval) {
        ...
    }
}

...

ScalarFunction sequenceFunction = ScalarFunctionImpl.create(Types.lookupMethod(SequenceFunction.class, 
"eval", Date.class, Date.class, IntervalSqlType.class));
rootSchema.getSubSchema("my_schema").add("sequence", sequenceFunction);
String sql = "select sequence('2024-09-08', '2024-12-12', interval '1' month) from my_table)";
ResultSet rs = calciteConnection.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);

IntervalSqlType type doesn't work, I get an exception - 'No assign rules for OTHER defined'. I tried to use String for interval parameter, but it just pass only value of interval - "+1" without any identifiers (MONTH, DAY etc)
Is there any way to pass sql interval as java parameter? Maybe there is a way to implement custom sql to java converter?
